# How can I send dynamically completed queries to database using JDBC and MySQL?

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

I want to send dynamically queries to database from my Java desktop application. I created an algorithm that generates the query each time in a form of a String and I'm wondering if I can pass it to the database without using PreparedStatements or stored procedures.

The query is always in this form: `SELECT * FROM  TABLE WHERE {} ;`
The WHERE clause always changes, including the values but also the columns of the table in the database change.

If I use stored procedures, the number of possible combinations I have to cover is like 50+, so I have to make 50 functions in the database, same with PreparedStatements. I am wondering if I can just pass the query straight from my Java application.

I tried to implement this using the Statement class of JDBC. Here is the stack trace:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Connection established

Database connection established.

Callable statement completed

Stored procedure executed.

Connection established

Database connection established.

Query generated : 

SELECT *
FROM PISTONS
WHERE
PISTONS.stroke = 2T;

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3602)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3906)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.example.motoparts/com.example.motoparts.PistonTableController.searchPistons(PistonTableController.java:307)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
    at com.example.motoparts/com.example.motoparts.DatabaseController.searchPistons(DatabaseController.java:36)
    at com.example.motoparts/com.example.motoparts.PistonTableController.searchPistons(PistonTableController.java:139)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: _from my Java desktop application..._  Is there a back-end server involved?  If no, and this is more than a toy app, the desktop app would have the JDBC connection string, which exposes the database to anybody that's looking.  See also:  SQL Injection attack

Comment: yes its like a toy app i am developing for my training. It has not a back-end server involved and it is exposed as you say but thats not what i asked

Comment: Sure - that can be done.  What have you tried?

Comment: As i said PreparedStatements let you change dynamically only the values you pass to the Database and not the Columns . StoredProcedures can be used one for each combination so they are not optimal. The only Class in JDBC which accepts an entire query in String form is the Statement Class. But it doesnt accept the query for some reason , it only works with queries without parameters , like SELECT*FROM TABLE; DELETE * FROM TABLE ; etc

Comment: “But it doesnt accept the query for some reason”. It sounds like this is the real problem. Tell us what error you get. Edit the question and paste in the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace says i did a syntax sql error , that triggered the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
But as you can see the query generated is valid.

Comment: Curly braces are valid in sql syntax?

Comment: thats an example of the form , check the edited question to see the query

Comment: `SELECT * FROM PISTONS WHERE PISTONS.stroke = 2T` is invalid sql syntax. `2T`must be escaped because it is not a number (integer, float, etc.), Hint: Use a gui for your database and run there your generated sql query. After some fixes, modify your Javacode based on the example